# How to add ajax to jquery-ui slider using ruby on rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, jquery-ui, slider

So I'm following this outdated tutorial on using the jquery-ui slider with rails 3 beta since it's the only one I've found.

My view which has the script

```
<p>
  <p>Showing all stocks between <span id="x_low_selected"><%= @price_range.first %></span> and <span id="x_high_selected"><%= @price_range.last %></span></p>
</p>
<div id="x_slider"></div>
<ul id="x_stock_list">
<%= render 'map' %>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
  $("#x_slider").slider( { 
    range: true,
    step: 1,
    max: <%= @price_range.last %>,
    min: <%= @price_range.first %>,
    values: [<%= @price_range.first %>, <%= @price_range.last %> ],
    stop: function(event, ui) {
    var prices = $('#x_slider').slider('option', 'values');
    $('#x_low_selected').html(prices[0]);
    $('#x_high_selected').html(prices[1]);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/users',
        type: "GET",
        data: { low: prices[0], high: prices[1] },
        dataType: 'json'
    });
   }
  });
});
</script>
```

model method for prices

```
def self.low_high_prices
  [User.minimum(:start), User.maximum(:end)]
end
```

and the index method in the controller which the ajax should call

```
def index
  @users = User.all
  unless params[:low] && params[:high]
    @users = User.all
    @json = User.all.to_gmaps4rails do |user, marker|
    marker.infowindow "<a href=/users/#{user.id}> #{user.name} </a>"
    marker.title user.name
  end
else
  @json = User.where("start >= params[:low] AND end <= params[:high]).to_gmaps4rails do |user, marker|
    marker.infowindow "<a href=/users/#{user.id}> #{user.name} </a>"
    marker.title user.name
  end
end
@price_range = User.low_high_prices
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @users }
  end
end
```

Does anyone know why the ajax call isn't being sent to the controller when the slider stops sliding?  Not sure if I would be able to use :remote => true because the slider is generated inside the div.

Thanks

Also I am currently using rails 3.2 with ruby 1.9.7

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding your problem, I don't think this is a rails problem so :remote won't matter. I assume the slider is rendering correctly. Can you tell if the event is firing at all (maybe with some logging or alert in the stop handler)? Not really familiar with the slider but everything looks right. You seeing any script errors?

Comment: no, but I'm not sure how to check for script errors.  From my initial tests though (adding alerts, changing the controller method) it seems that the ajax function is not being called at all.  Also when I attempt to add $success to the javascript the slider doesn't appear when I load the page.

Comment: addition: calling alert(); in the stop function works fine, it's called when the slider stops moving, so it seems the part that's not working is the ajax call itself.

Comment: Do you know how to monitor the network traffic with chrome developer tools or firebug?

Comment: I just installed the firefox add-on for it and am debugging the javascript but the ajax seems to be working fine.  I added breakpoints for the ajax call and it passes through it with no errors.

Comment: however even though the ajax doesn't hit any errors, I'm not sure the rails method is being called which is weird.

Comment: Can you hit the URL directly?

Comment: directly? I am able to go to http://localhost:3000/users fine if that's what you mean, also I added a logger function in the index method in the controller and it appears fine when you stop the slider so the ajax does seem to be calling the method.  The interesting thing though is that's the only thing that currently seems to be working as even if I change @ users = User.all to @users = User.first in the else part of the if statement, nothing changes.

Comment: Add a complete callback to your Ajax call set a breakpoint there and see if it is hit. Complete should fire regardless of success or error. Keep an eye on the network traffic (you should see some kind of network tab in firebug) and see what kind of response comes from the server. I have had an issue before where jquery didn't understand the response data type (which you have as json) and neither the error or success callbacks fired.

Comment: I added a complete callback and it worked fine, breakpoint hit it and alert message popped up.  As for the net tab nothing unusual popped up, just a bunch of get requests for google maps api, css, etc.

Comment: I added .ajaxSuccess and .ajaxError as well but the only time both of those are called is when the page is loading, moving the slider triggers the complete function but not the success or error function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that your call is going through to the controller, and the controller is returning JSON data.

The problem is that your `$.ajax` call is doing nothing with the JSON data received.

You need to add a callback function to handle the JSON data passed back in some way in the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/users',
    type: "GET",
    data: { low: prices[0], high: prices[1] },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        alert("Success: " + data);
        //do something with the data here.
    }
});
```

Also, looking at the controller code, it will only pass back the contents of `@users` in the JSON data, not the contents of `@json` or anything else - not sure if that was your intention or not.

Comment: thanks this worked, I have a second question on how to update the google map partial with the retrieved marker data but I'll create another question for that.